# Python: Hide sub-process print out on the terminal and continue the script while sub is running

Tags: python, debian, subprocess, scapy

is there a way to use python2.6 with either `subprocess.Popen()` or `os.system()` to run two tasks? Example the script will run "`airodump-ng`" first then this process is sub and is hidden(meaning will not print out from terminal) after which continue run the rest of the script which contain "`sniff`" function of scapy. I been researched but I only found windows version and python3. By the way I running on debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) in combination with [`subprocess.PIPE`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE):

```
p = Popen(['airodump-ng', …], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

If you want to wait until the process has finished use:

```
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

If you omit the code above `airodump-ng` will run in the background and produce no visible output, while you can continue with your python code.

Another method would be to use `os.devnull` to redirect the output of `airodump-ng` to, this will completly get rid of any output produced:

```
devnull = os.open(os.devnull, os.O_WRONLY)
p = Popen(['airodump-n', …], stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull)
```

Comment: nice, but how can i let the `airodump-ng` run for awhile first then continue with my python code? I used `time.sleep(5)` but it seem not working well. Any ideas?

Comment: okay my mistake, I guess is other problems that cause it. My scenario is to output `airodump-ng` to cap file and I use `sniff(store=0, offline='myTraffic.cap', prn=sniffFunction)` where the sniffFunction is `if p.haslayer(Dot11):` but it seem to print out a few of the packets only and the script had stopped and the `airodump-ng` is still running on the background. =\

Comment: seems like the `sniff` function thinks the capture has ended and thus returns. Maybe there is a function in `scapy` which  doesn't return (interprets it as a stream). Unfortunatly I don't know enought about scapy and cap files to help here.

Comment: okay, but it seem like running the `airodump-ng` twice. when i use `ps -a` it has two pid cmd of `airodump-ng`. But i can only kill one and the another when i gonna kill it gave me `-bash: kill: (2241) - No such process`

Answer (score 0):

In the spot where you put the command `airodump-ng` replace that part with `timeout 'X's airodump-ng mon'X'`